# How trigger events on elements created afterwards other events in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have replicated windows calculator. I am stuck with the "memory tab".

I need to create click events on the three buttons: MC M+ M- as below (top right of the screen).
[image]

The problem is that these buttons (and all the elements around) are created afterwards every time i click "MS" on the main calculator (left of the screen, above main buttons).

```
function addMemoryValue(){
  const uls = document.createElement("ul");
  const lis = document.createElement("li");
  const h2s = document.createElement("h2");
  h2s.textContent = Number(display.textContent);
  const h3s = document.createElement("h3");

  uls.appendChild(lis);
  lis.appendChild(h2s);
  h2s.appendChild(h3s);

  let valueBtn = ["MC", "M+", "M-"];

  valueBtn.forEach((element) => {
  const memoryBtn = document.createElement("button");
  memoryBtn.setAttribute("value", element);
  memoryBtn.textContent = element;
  const memorySpn = document.createElement("span");
  memorySpn.appendChild(memoryBtn);
  memoryBtn.classList.add("btnsave");
  h3s.appendChild(memorySpn);

  const buttonTest = document.getElementsByClassName("btnsave");
  console.log(buttonTest.textContent);
  })
```

I want to iterate theses buttons and create if statements according to the textContent but I am not sure how to target the buttons since they don't exist yet.

If for example I try the following:

```
const buttonTest = document.getElementsByClassName("btnsave");
console.log(buttonTest.textContent);
```

I get "undifined" regardless wheteher console.log is inside or outside the function.

Comment: `buttonTest` will be an array, not an element. See https://plainjs.com/javascript/selecting/select-elements-by-class-name-3/

Comment: Ok with console.log(buttonTest) I get the html collection. Now I want to iterate each items and run eventListener according to their attribute/index. The problem is that when I console.log(buttonTest.item(0)) to inspect the first item I get "null". What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can add click event handlers directly where you create the buttons like this:

```js
var clickHandler = function() {
    console.log("button clicked");
};

var button = document.createElement("button");
button.textContent = "test";
button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);

document.getElementById("container").appendChild(button);
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```

**Update after OPs comment:**

This snippet will create three buttons, when a button is clicked and add three different event handlers to them.

```js
var createButton = function(title, clickHandler) {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.textContent = title;
    button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);

    return button;
};

var removeButtons = function() {
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    
    while (container.firstChild) {
      container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    }
};

var createButtons = function() {
    removeButtons();
    
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    
    container.appendChild(createButton("button 1", () => console.log("button 1 clicked")));
    container.appendChild(createButton("button 2", () => console.log("button 2 clicked")));
    container.appendChild(createButton("button 3", () => console.log("button 3 clicked")));
};

document.getElementById('create').addEventListener("click", createButtons);
document.getElementById('remove').addEventListener("click", removeButtons);
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px dashed teal;
  min-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<button id="create">create buttons</button>
<button id="remove">remove buttons</button>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping but my issues is different. To semplify with your example: I need the click event on "test" button generates other three buttons, iterate them and running three different addevent listeners.

Comment: I updated my answer with another snippet. Is this what you want?

Comment: Kind of. let's assume there are several ul with the same elements you created above(htmlCollection of uls). How can I make sure that when I press the button 1, the "button 1 cliked" is actually added to the "current" ul  and not on the first child of the htmlcollection?.

Comment: You can pass references to all the elements you need, when you create the click handlers. You can think of it as a "context" for your handlers.

Comment: I sorted out with event delegation. Thank you.